# I am running Hibernate project from command prompt After compiling I am getting error About Hibernate Depreciated API

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

While doing this I am getting error in the command prompt that.
Error : src\com\example\util\Hibernate.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
How to fix this issue.

I am getting to store the data in the database using hibernate but without any IDE.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.